# How can I colour things in OpenGL ES 2.0 based on their depth?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm writing an OpenGL ES 2.0 game (on iOS). How can I create a shader (since I assume this would be simpler to do in a shader) so that geometry further from the origin (on the Z axis) appears darker?

The water in this image illustrates the effect I have in mind

[image: Zarch]
<sub>(source: [bytecellar.com](http://www.bytecellar.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Zarch_screen.png))</sub>

Comment: You should probably look for Open GL ES 2.0 lighting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do if you just want to use the Z position of your geometry. You could have a vertex shader like the following:

```
attribute vec4 position;

varying float zDepth;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 newPosition = modelViewProjMatrix * position;
    gl_Position = newPosition;
    zDepth = (2.0 - (1.0 + newPosition.z))/2.0;
}
```

and a fragment shader like

```
varying highp float zDepth;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(zDepth, zDepth, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

which would produce the following look:

[image: Depth-shaded OpenGL teapot]

I have an example of this within [this iPad sample code](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip) I assembled for my OpenGL ES 2.0 class.

Comment: That works well, especially if you incorporate the colour of the objects. The '2.0' in the code needs changing to whatever your z depth is though.

Answer (score 0):

I did a rather interesting test with what @brad provide. I just change the line:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, zDepth);
```

Nothing happen to the alpha. Is it me or is there something else is missing as for the `Alpha`?

Comment: Either most of your depth values are really close to one, or GL_BLEND is disabled, as well as glBlendFunc is not set.